# XNA Collision detection with Intersects()

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I want to make a Platform object solid from every side so that the Player could not pass through it. I think the most simple idea is to use a "previous position" variable. Especially with the *Intersects()* method (I like it)!

If Player intersects, then move to last position. But nothing happens. Most likely I couldn't figure out how to implement proper "previous position".

Here's what I have in class Player:

```
public void Collision(Sprite obj)
    {
        Vector2 previousPosition = this.Position;
        if (this.Bounds.Intersects(obj.Bounds))
        {
            this.Position = previousPosition;
        }
    }
```

Player and Platform inherit Sprite class which has this property:

```
public Rectangle Bounds
{
    get
    {
       return new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y,
                             Texture.Width, Texture.Height);
    }
}
```

---

Another idea I tried was to use a bool *isSolid* but I didn't know how to work the logic.
I've searched and tried things around the net(including stackoverflow) for maybe 4-5 hours. This is supposed to be so simple, yet I can't understand it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple. Take look at the previousPosition and you see the problem. I'm gonna explain the problem like this.

X is my current X • Prev X is my previous X •
• I move forward in X axis so X increments by 1
• x is now 1
• prev X is now x (so it's basically 1)

x hits the object so x becomes = prev X

So basically x becomes itself everytime it checks if it's hitting the target.

Solution 1.
Set the *previousPosition* variable to the *currentPosition* before you move, so *currentPosition* value changes and *previousPosition* is not the same as *currentPosition* everytime.

In short this is the order

- set *prevPos* to *playerPos*
- move the player
- set *currentPos* to *playerPos*
- check for colliding
- set *playerPos* to *prevPos* if they did collide

EDIT:
The code you provided does this:

```
PreviousPosition = this.Position;
this.Position = currentPosition;
```

First line is correct but the second line that you have in the collide function needs to be changed to

```
this.Position = previousPosition;
```

If that doesn't work there is an other solution.  Regards, Tuukka.

Comment: @Bruno Did you try to code it this way? If you did, please provide the code you tried on your post. There is another way if all that failed.

Comment: I see. It makes sense but still doesn't work. The Player passes through the platform. I created a static property for the Platform which I passed as a parameter to the Collision() method. 
I also have a string output for Collision on the screen(Debugging purpose). Since putting a breakpoint on the Update() just loops back and forth to Draw() and nothing happens. Here's what I have, to make it more clear: [link](http://i.imgur.com/XyiN2HS.png)

Comment: Ahh, I saw what you did wrong. The collision check sets the player position to currentPosition. You need to set 'this.Position = previousPosition' in the Collision check function.

Comment: You know, I *did* thought about that but then immediately got confused. I'm drawing it on paper. I tend to understand it for a few seconds then forget. But I'll get the hang of it. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Bruno Oh sorry, you did everything right the first time, I just misplaced the currentPosition in the wrong line, my bad. I corrected my post so it's fixed now.